# How do you add Facebook shimmering to images and UIViews?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios-animations

I'm trying out Facebook shimmering library and I was able to add shimmering to text label using this code.

```
    self.shimmeringView = FBShimmeringView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)!))
    self.shimmeringView.contentView = navLabel
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.shimmeringView
    self.shimmeringView.shimmering = true
```

However, I am unable to make an image or an UIImage shimmer. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: please add the code you did for shimmering a UIImageView.

Comment: I tried something like this for shimmering ImageView @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView! var shimmer: FBShimmeringView! override func viewDidLoad() { shimmer = FBShimmeringView(frame: self.imageView.frame) shimmer.shimmering = true }

Comment: @Shubhank I've added the code below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing for shimmering the `UIImageView` is wrong.

1. You did not add shimmer to the view as a subview.
2. You did not set the `UIImageView` as the `contentView` for the shimmer.

Update your code with something like that:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

var shimmer: FBShimmeringView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    shimmer = FBShimmeringView(frame: self.imageView.frame)
    shimmer.contentView = imageView
    self.view.addSubview(shimmer)
    shimmer.isShimmering = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 with Shimmer (1.0.2):

```
var imageView: UIImageView!

var shimmer: FBShimmeringView!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    shimmer = FBShimmeringView(frame: self.imageView.frame)
    shimmer.contentView = imageView
    self.view.addSubview(shimmer)
    shimmer.isShimmering = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use constraints as well, without initializing the shimmer view every time when the view layouts the subviews:

```
let shimmer = FBShimmeringView(frame: .zero)
view.addSubview(shimmer)
shimmer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: shimmer, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navLabel, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: shimmer, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navLabel, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: shimmer, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navLabel, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: shimmer, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with @Shubhank answer, even though most of the answer is fine.

Using viewDidLoad instead of viewDidLayoutSubviews for shimmer frame didn't give me results that I wanted.

So I updated the code, and everything works fine.

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

var shimmer: FBShimmeringView!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        shimmer = FBShimmeringView(frame: self.imageView.frame)
        shimmer.contentView = imageView
        self.view.addSubView(shimmer)
        shimmer.shimmering = true
}
```